# Is Android 11 "flashable" on Xperia X F5121?

Tags: sony-xperia, android-11

sorry I'm not sure if "flashable" is even a word but my Xperia X
is stuck on Android 8 and I've seen an article speaking about the possibility to upgrade it to Android 11 with TWRP recovery tool.

The tool crashes on my Xperia.

You may say "just get newer phone" which is a sound advice but the thing is my Xperia X is practically new phone. No scratches, no visible wear so getting new phone would be just a waste of money.

Can anyone confirm that it didn't brick your F5121 after flashing Android 11 on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Comment: My question was rather "Have you used TWRP to flush newest ROM on your F5121 without bricking the phone ?"

Comment: I've posted on XDA forums 2 days ago with no responses.

Comment: there exist no android 11 you can flash therefore your question is pointless. most recent seen so far is [android 10](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4015131)

Comment: OK, so the article I came across is a spam then.

Comment: It is strange though if the ROM is compatible with the model why user isn't prompted in the phone for direct upgrade like it was with previous Android versions.

Comment: Those ROMs are unofficial ROMs, not released by Sony and neither by LineageOS (pupular custo ROM project with a relative high trust level). Therefore they can work, but they can also harm your device or even contain malware. On custom ROMs everything is possible. Through the official update function you can only find and install official releases from Sony. BTW: usually you only "flush the toilet", I think you mean "flash" (because the memory is called flash memory).

Comment: smartphones are [embedded devices](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_on_embedded_systems) each firmware is built unique. you wouldn't expect netgear firmware will work on linksys wifi router

Comment: @Robert Thanks for clarifying "flush" and "flash" for me. I sometimes use them interchangeably and it makes some people chuckle.

Comment: Well in the XDA thread I can see that the ROM had few F5121 owners stuck on splash screen. So it's not 100% compatible.

Comment: I'll close this question as it doesn't have clear-cut answer. There **might** be Android 11 version out there but it's not official and can potentially brick the phone.